# Select with IMDB option work slowly in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, in-memory-database, in-memory

There is a table with 20 columns and 10,000 rows in it.
A query to retrieve one column (SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE) from it **without** the IMDB option on is **faster** than with the option enabled (the documentation says that there should be a gain when using this type of request).
After the query is completed, SELECT * FROM V$IM_SEGMENTS shows that the table is stored in RAM.
Tell me what could be the problem.

Comment: But are the next requests still faster without the option?

Comment: How do the explain plans compare between the query with the IM option on and off?  Is the plan for when the IM option is on even showing it is using the in-memory store?  Is the column in question indexed?  What is the data type?  Have you gathered stats recently?  Has any of the table been read into the buffer cache before your tests or not?  Lots of factors here, but you are probably not dealing with a problem.  Also, a table with 10,000 rows is not much of a candidate for using IM.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso As when. Sometimes they work slower (not much) and sometimes faster (and many times). I can't understand in what there can be a reason.

Comment: @unleashed Before I run queries, I clear the buffer cache with a command alter system flush buffer_cache and alter system flush shared_pool. The index on the column is not created. After the IMDB option is enabled, the plan shows that it uses the the in-memory store. Data Types in the table number, varchar, date. Gathered statistics recently.
And I tried with the table and in 100,000 and in 1,000,000 lines. The result is the same....

Comment: @Svetlana A couple of thoughts.  Your question is impossible to answer as there too many factors and you've not provided enough information.  Also, flushing the buffer cache is not necessarily a valid test as your running system will have rows in the cache, table and index. 
 Further, IM option does not always mean improved performance in all cases.  I suggest you read up on the IM option further to understand what it does, how it is different, and where it would benefit, if at all, for you.  Beyond that, if you still need help, you'll have to provide more info, DDL, explain plans, etc.

Comment: As @unleashed mentioned we need to confirm with query plan to see why query is slow. As of  Oracle 12.1.0.2 the optimizer may choose to serve the query from disk instead of inmemory if there is a DML happened on the inmemory enabled table. If you have Oracle 12.2.0.1 even the queries on table on which DML happened will be faster due to optimizations went through in this release. It would be easy to answer if you provide more information.